# CosmosDb: Call a stored procedure from another stored procedure or trigger

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In Azure Cosmos Db, is there a way to call a stored procedure from another stored procedure? What about UDF? Can I call a UDF from another UDF, Stored procedure, or Trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to call a stored procedure from another stored
>   procedure? Or Trigger?

It is not possible to execute a stored procedure within a stored procedure or trigger.However, you can define JS functions inside a stored procedure, which can be referenced, called and re-used from within that stored procedure.

> UDF?

Can't call another udf within a udf,but you can try nested udf. The UDF need to be used in sql like `select udf.test(c) from c`.

So,you could execute it like below:

```
SELECT udf.bbb(udf.aaa(c.id)) FROM c
```